# php code not returning desired results

Tags: php, smarty

This part of the code isn't executing properly in my 'products_list.tpl' file.

```
{* Show Edit button for administrators *}
{if $obj->mShowEditButton}
    <form action="{$obj->mEditActionTarget}" target="_self" method="post" class="edit-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{$obj->mProducts[k].product_id}" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Product Details" />
    </form>
{/if}
```

It's returning this

```
<form action="http://phpcs5/regional-d1" target="_self" method="post" class="edit-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="10" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Product Details" />
</form>
```

instead of (the desired output)

```
<form action="http://phpcs5/" target="_self" method="post" class="edit-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="3" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Product Details" />
</form>
```

Can anyone please help me? I can give you any details you ask. Thank you.

Here it is:

```
public function init() {
    // Prepare the Edit button
    $this->mEditActionTarget = Link::Build(str_replace(VIRTUAL_LOCATION, '', getenv('REQUEST_URI')));
    if (isset($_SESSION['admin_logged'])
            && $_SESSION['admin_logged'] == true
            && isset($_POST['product_id'])) {
        if (isset($this->_mDepartmentId)
                && isset($this->_mCategoryId)) {
            header('Location: ' . htmlspecialchars_decode(
                    Link::ToProductAdmin($this->_mDepartmentId,
                            $this->_mCategoryId,
                            (int)$_POST['product_id'])));
        }
        else {
            $product_locations = Catalog::GetProductLocations((int)$_POST['product_id']);
            if (count($product_locations) > 0) {
                $department_id = $product_locations[0]['department_id'];
                $category_id = $product_locations[0]['category_id'];
                header('Location: ' . htmlspecialchars_decode(
                        Link::ToProductAdmin($department_id,
                                $category_id,
                                (int)$_POST['product_id'])));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are getting the wrong object?

Comment: @putvante +1. You should check that $obj is the the right one before assigning it.

Comment: also, can you post $obj->mEditActionTarget code